# How to run Nodejs Server from PHP script?

Tags: php, node.js, ubuntu, exec, chmod

I have a PHP server which is the main application.
I have a Nodejs Server which is a sub-application.

Nodejs Server is used for a Notification Mechanism. I want to be able to disable the notification mechanism from my main application which runs on PHP.

There is a button. On clicking it, I change my Nodejs config file and now I want to restart Nodejs server.
I imagine I can do something like this in PHP:

exec("kill `sudo lsof -t -i:4849`");
   exec("node server.js");

Prospective problems:
1)Permissions issue : I imagine this could be solved by giving my apache user the ownership of node application. Am I right?
2)Exec : Doing an exec causes my browser to go on loading. I do netstat and find the Nodejs server running. This is the problem that is worrying me. I suppose I need to do some fork and exec method so that the child process(Nodejs ) runs independently.

Please help.

Solution :

```
    exec("fuser -k ". NODEAPPPORT ."/tcp > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
    exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid node "'.NODEPATH.'/app.js" > 
    /dev/null 2>&1 &"');
```

I redirected the stdout and stderr to /dev/null.
I run it as an independent process.It works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be: 
**don't.**

Run the Node server as a standalone server, either through a framework such as [Express](https://expressjs.com/) or something else. You could then expose your Node app's endpoint(s) (which would be the simplest solution IMO) via a private network and/or use a simple authorization mechanism between your PHP app and your Node app. You can then start/stop the notification system via that simple API endpoint instead of killing/restarting your Node app every time. Suppose that it crashes upon startup for whichever reason, you wouldn't be able to tell that it's down from your PHP app.

I don't know how exactly your notifications app works, but I'm guessing it's handling some sort of a stream which you can easily turn off without killing the entire Node server.